# Sending remainder email dynamically node js

Tags: node.js, express, cron, microservices, eventqueue

I have an application where I have to remind the user **1 week, 2 days** and also **2 hours** before of the appointment date.

I have implemented this with cron-job already, but wanted to know is there any better approach, such as event queues, micro-services.

Please share your input.

Thank you.

Comment: Which exact module or program are you using for your cron implementation?  Please provide a link to it's doc.  What is it not doing that you think you need?

Comment: @jfriend00, I have created an API, and that API will get triggered from server using CURL, in every 10 mins. I am looking for other options, just to come out of the cron job that is hitting every 10 mins.

Comment: @KiranUppunda You can try https://cloud.google.com/scheduler